# How to bind different properties to SelectedItem and SelectedIValue of ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox

I have a thread that updates the current `Mode` property every second. I also want an option to be able to set a mode within the same cell in datagrid. So, in **not** editing mode I just show the mode. In editing mode, I show a populated `ComboBox`. 
Now,

- to be able to show the selected item in `ComboBox`, when I enter the editing mode, I bind the `SelectedItem` to `Mode`.
- to be able to get the changes back to the ViewModel I bind `SelectedValue` to a different property. ( I need to bind to a different property since 'Mode' is updated every second and will overwrite the selected value).

The problem is that though `SelectedItem` is bound with `Mode=OneTime` it still triggers `SelectedValue` property. I want the `SelectedValue` to be triggered only when user select a value.

I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do. So, how I can achieve this? Other approaches are welcome (even if I need to use a different control).

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Mode">
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding Mode}"/>
      </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Modes}}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding Mode, Mode=OneTime}"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding ModeToSet, Mode=OneWayToSource}" 
         />
     </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: It is unclear, at least to me, why `StatusToSet` has to remain (null) until an actual user selection? Why not push the selection to another property **when** the `SelectionChange` event occurs? Since `StatusToSet` has intermediate values which are not wanted?

Comment: @OmegaMan, it should have been `ModeToSet` (I've updated it). When you do `SelectedItem="{Binding Mode}"` in `CellEditingTemplate` it makes the source to be updated. I don't want it to be updated when you just enter editing mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The premise of what needs to be done is not attainable due to the way the combobox works and how `Mode` is constantly changing in the background.

Why?

> The problem is that though SelectedItem is bound with Mode=OneTime it
>   still triggers SelectedValue property.

As it should. `OneTime` as per the docs ([BindingMode Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) states:

"*Updates the binding target when the application starts or when the data context changes.*"

The data context as per your design is always changing once a second. If one reads farther into the description it states

"*This type of binding is appropriate if you are using data where either a snapshot of the current state is appropriate to use or the data is truly static. ... This is essentially a simpler form of OneWay binding...*"

And if one reads up on `OneWay` bindings

"*Updates the binding target (target) property when the binding source (source) changes. This type of binding is appropriate if the control being bound is implicitly read-only.*"

A combo box is ultimately designed to change both `SelectedItem` and to get the value off of `SelectedItem` into `SelectedValue`

> I want the SelectedValue to be triggered only when user select a value.

The problem is not going out of the control, it is what is coming in....

Create a test project and the combobox behaves the way you specify, selected value is only triggered when a user selects a value. Comboboxes only sets the `SelectedX` properties when a choice is made **or an outside value has changed one** so it changes the other.

Since `Mode` is constantly changing it is pushing the change into the selection, not visa versa.

### Suggestion To Fix

I suggest you take a snapshot of mode and place that into a `ModeOnEdit` variable and bind that. When the user makes the selection, capture the event and change the actual `Mode`.

---

### Test Project

Bind to your own data source, mine was Ships. Ships is a list with and `Name` as a property on that object. `ToString` on the ship object returns `Name`.

Here is the result, there are  two textboxes which show the state of the selected item/value. A button to set the selected value and the combobox itself.

[image]

```
<Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1">SelectedItem</Label>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=cbMain}"/>
<Label Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">SelectedValue</Label>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding SelectedValue, ElementName=cbMain}"/>
<Button Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Click="ChangeSelectedValue">Set Selected Value</Button>
<ComboBox Name="cbMain"
            Grid.Row="5"
            Grid.Column="2"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Ships}"
            SelectedValuePath="Name"/>
```

-- Code behind

```
private void ChangeSelectedValue(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    cbMain.SelectedValue = "Pacific Silver";
}
```

Comment: I took your comments into consideration and added additional property `ModeToTest` and it solved the problem. `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Modes}}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding ModeToTest}"                
         />`